# How to insert a 15 minute time slot for every day of the year

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to create a database thta reflects a customisable stock level for every 15 minute window for an entire year.

My database structure looks like this:

| time_period | day | month | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 00:15 | 1 | 1 | 15 |
| .... | ... | ... | ... |
| 23:45 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 00:00 | 2 | 1 | 20 |
| .... | ... | ... | ... |
| 23:45 | 31 | 12 | 0 |

So in total there would be 96 * 366 = 35,136 rows in this particular table that I want to insert. The `time_period` increments every 15 minutes (96 slots per day) for 266 days of the year.

Are there any ways to easily insert this data using a mySQL query or a loop?

So far the best option I've come up with is to manually generate the data into a JSON or CSV file and then import to the DB `FROM FILE` - it seems like there should be an easier way to do this though?

EDIT: Attempted using Recursive Common Table Expressions as suggested by a commenter. My DB is running mySQL 5.7 so unfortunately this isn't an option

Comment: [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive)

Comment: or just do it in excel with formulas and import the rows manually :P

Comment: Nice - I didn't know about recursive common expressions - will play with that and see if I can can up with something slick

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on mySQL 5.7 so CTEs are not an option

Comment: If so then use X copies of synthetic numbers table (`SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 .. UNION SELECT N`). For example, 4 copies 14 values each. Or `id` from some system table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be quicker and easier to write a script to just insert 35,040 rows in a loop:

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxxxxxxx', database='test')
cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)

stmt = """INSERT INTO MyTable SET t = %s"""

time = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
end = datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

while time < end:
    cursor.execute(stmt, (time,))
    time += datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)

cnx.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks Bill - yes I think this is the way to go. Will give that datetime.timedelta function a shot